# Unexpected output while using %3d (maximum field width specifier in scanf())

Tags: c, scanf

**Source Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    printf("Enter: ");
    scanf("%3d %3d %3d",&a,&b,&c);
    printf("%d",b);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter: 1234 5678 9
4
--------------------------------
Process exited after 7.322 seconds with return value 1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

When I use `scanf("%3d %3d %3d",&a,&b,&c);` here why does b get the value 4 and not 456?

Using `%3d %3d %3d` should extract (thrice) three consecutive non-whitespace characters and place them in the variables `a`, `b` and `c` respectively, isn't it ?

Comment: Pretty expected, if you ask me.. There is space after `4`

Comment: Input `123456789` instead of `1234 5678 9`. Since the space works as a delimiter

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, but `%3d %3d %3d` is supposed to neglect whitespace characters, isn't it? That's what I read in my textbook. My question is why it doesn't neglect the spaces, even though it is supposed to.

Comment: It's called _maximum field width_, not _minimum_ !!

Comment: @Blue can you quote the book?

Comment: "three *consecutive* non-whitespace characters", yes. `4 56` isn't consecutive.

Comment: @SouravGhosh "The consecutive nonwhitespace characters that define a data item collectively define a field. It is possible to limit the number of such characters by specifying a maximum filed width for that data item. To do so an unsigned integer indicating field width is placed within the control string, between the percent sign and convertion character."

Comment: @melpomene Oh, I think I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: "Yes, but %3d %3d %3d is supposed to neglect whitespace characters, isn't it?" -- no, not exactly.  The spaces between field directives match any number of whitespace characters, including zero, *between fields*, and `%d` directives ignore *leading* whitespace.  Each field still ends at whitespace if it does not end earlier for some other reason.

Comment: `3` means: "consume **at most** 3 characters here", i.e. **maximum field width.**

Comment: I don't understand the reason for the downvote...

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, gotcha!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Right. Sourav pointed that out. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Did you check the manual for `scanf` yet? You're asking us to read the manuals for you.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, I did. The manual wasn't very clearly written (or, it was not clear enough for *me*). So I had to ask here. You can see that I can even quoted my textbook (Byron S Gottfried, 2nd edition).

Comment: Then you should quote the parts of that manual that you read, too. That way this would be useful to other people that are wondering about the same section in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SouravGosh points out %*n*d where n is an number format specifies the maximum number of characters to be read as part of this field.

So you enter "1234␣567␣8", a consumes 123; b consumes 4 and stops because of the ␣; and then c consumes 567.

Comment: Detail, the width does not include leading whitespace characters.  `sscanf("\t\t\t1234", "%3d", &a);` will  set `x == 123`